# Bootstrap columns in fluid container

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Im trying to set out my web page so in the top left corner i have a welcome message, and in the top right corner i have a log-out link. I'm using a fluid container, which holds 2 columns, one for left and one for right. For some reason both messages are spawning on the very right hand side of the screen. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: can you please provide some code in a fiddle?. Its hard to understand without seeing the code.

Comment: @Pbk1303 http://jsfiddle.net/ua6c0apy/

Answer (score 2):

The correct class in bootstrap is `col-md-6`, not `column-md-6`.

Comment: oh god....spent too long programming coding, dont know how i missed that, thanks!

Comment: No problem. Been there done that :).